# Where is the alertbox?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the following code, I'm getting an alert box, but as you can see in the code there is no alert used. so where it's coming from.

```
var mypostrequest=new ajaxRequest();
  mypostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (mypostrequest.readyState==4){
      if (mypostrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
        if(mypostrequest.responseText == "true")
      {
         err.style.display = "none";   
         captcha.style.borderColor = "green";
         document.validForm.submit();
         return true;
     } else{ 
       captcha.style.borderColor = "red";
       err.style.display = "inline-block";
       err.innerHTML = "invalid captcha. Try again."
       captcha.focus();
         return false;
     }          
  }
```

the alert it's showing is `"true".`

this is ajaxRequest()

```
function ajaxRequest(){
 var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]; //activeX versions to check for in IE
 if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
   try{
    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i]);
   }
   catch(e){
    //suppress error
   }
  }
 }
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
 else
  return false;
```

}

Comment: Not in this code? Show `ajaxRequest`'s code.

Comment: just this code...

<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php

if (strtolower($_POST['captcha']) ==  $_SESSION["captcha"]) {

    echo "true";
}
 else {

     echo "false";
    }

   //unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
?>


just echoing true or false,

Comment: @epoch, tried that deleted all the alert's but still i'm getting true as alert..

Comment: are you sure the cache is cleared?

Comment: yup, done everything even, restarted my laptop..

Comment: well then the alert is there. at which point does it alert?

Comment: when I submit the form, it check's the captcha using ajax, which is the code above, at this line if(mypostrequest.responseText == "true") the alert box pops..

Comment: Solved.. don't know how, but when I done as below, 
var data = mypostrequest.responseText;
      if(data == "true")   , instead of my above comment....